# Parse text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text-parsing

I am parsing multiple text files in MATLAB and each time I store the result in the main array, but the problem that the data haven't the same size!
example:

```
  t(i,:) = x; 
  % x data array from file i
```

ex:

```
  t(1,:) = [ 5 4 3 2 1];
  t(2,:) = [ 10 9 8 7 6 5];
  t(3,:) = [ 11 12 13 14];
```

the size of x's is different, how i can store such these data (dynamic size) in the array!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store it in a cell array like this:

```
  t{1} = [ 5 4 3 2 1];
  t{2} = [ 10 9 8 7 6 5];
  t{3} = [ 11 12 13 14];
```

and use them like this:

```
>> t(1)
ans = 
    [1x5 double]

>> t{2}
ans =
    10     9     8     7     6     5

>> t
t = 
    [1x5 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x4 double]

>> t{:}
ans =
     5     4     3     2     1

ans =
    10     9     8     7     6     5

ans =
    11    12    13    14

>> t{2}(1,2)
ans =
    9

>> t{2}(1,2:end)
ans =
     9     8     7     6     5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cell array to hold numeric arrays of various sizes. For instance

```
rows_cell = {};
rows_cell{1} = [ 5 4 3 2 1];
rows_cell{2} = [ 10 9 8 7 6 5];
rows_cell{3} = [ 11 12 13 14];
```

To access data:

```
rows_cell{2}(1,2)

ans =

  9

rows_cell{3}(1,4)

ans =

 14
```